# Does DeepSQL require a new MySQL installation?

Tags: mysql, deepsql

Does DeepSQL require a new MySQL installation or can I add it to my existing environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I work at Deep) DeepSQL is installed as a pluggable storage engine for MySQL. We currently support MySQL 5.5 and 5.6 as well as Percona Server 5.5 and 5.6. The DeepSQL plugin is designed to install into the binary distributions from mysq.com as well as the the ones from the Ubuntu and IUS repositories. Details can be found at http://deepis.com/product-documentation/deepsql-installation-guide-rel-330